# Facing issue on exposing service in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using openshift and I am unable to access service from outside. I have 2 yaml files service, and deployment. I am pulling nginx image. image is pulled successfully and service is created but i am unable to access nginx page from browser nor curl is working from cli.

below is the output of `oc get all command`

```
NAME                TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/nginx-svc   NodePort   17x.x.x.x  <none>        80:3000x/TCP   15h
```

deployment and everything is running.

Answer (score 1):

A `Service` is only accessible within the cluster. To access your `Service` from outside the cluster, you'll need to add a `Route` / `Ingress` object.

You can also check my answer on the following question to understand the difference between Routes and Services: [kubernetes vs openshift (routes and services)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354040/kubernetes-vs-openshift-routes-and-services/62361379#62361379)

So the easiest way to create such a `Route` would be to use the `oc expose` command like so:

```
oc expose svc nginx-svc
```

Then you can use `oc get routes` to see the URL for that Route.

Comment: route is also created. but still no success.

Comment: Well, what is the error message? What have you tried? How are you accessing the Route? Where is your cluster located and can you access it? Please add this information to your original question and we may be able to help you further.